# Installing mysqludf library on CentOS x64

Tags: mysql, mysql-udf

I've been googling a lot about the problem that I have trying to install MySQL library.

I've downloaded library files from https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys and placed it on digitalocean server (running on CentOS x64) on location: /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin

Library's Makefile was altered so now it looks like this:

```
install:
    gcc -m64 -fPIC -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -I. -shared lib_mysqludf_sys.c -o     /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/lib_mysqludf_sys.so -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

When I try to install the library from terminal using following command:

```
mysql -u root -p mysql < /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/lib_mysqludf_sys.sql
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1126 (HY000) at line 26: Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so' (errno: 22 /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/lib_mysqludf_sys.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32)
```

Googling this error I've found [this](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2009/01/repository-for-mysql-udfs-new-syseval.html) potential solution but it didn't help. Could anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: have you found out the answer to your problem?

Comment: No, I found alternative way to avoid need for this library.

Comment: Don't bother, I found a way to install this library for both on my local and production servers :)